# Imshow plot hiding the peaks when plotting large datasets in python

Tags: python, image

I am trying to plot a large dataset(of 50000 points) using image plot imshow. The peaks of the data are hidden due to compression. They are only visible when zoomed in. How can I assign the peak values to pixels so that they are visible. Interpolation 'nearest' and 'none' not helping. Below is the code and plot . Any ideas will be helpful

```
    draw_data = self.B[:, 0:50000]
    self.mpl_widget.canvas.axes.imshow(draw_data, cmap='jet', origin='lower', aspect='auto', extent=self.extent)
    formatter = ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: float(x / self.distance_scale_factor))
    self.mpl_widget.canvas.axes.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
    self.mpl_widget.canvas.axes.set_xlabel(self.default_distance_label, fontsize=font_size)
    self.mpl_widget.canvas.axes.set_ylabel('Time(seconds)', fontsize=font_size)
    self.mpl_widget.canvas.draw()
```

Full Plot

[image]

Zoomed Plot

[image]

Comment: Try to display your pictures.

Comment: Displaying zoomed one should be enough. Btw, both are exactly the same.